# Make boostrap modal X be above modal, not in it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Is there anyway that I can get the `x` on the bootstrap modal to appear above the modal instead of in the header section?  I have been trying some css that almost works but makes it look messy.  Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

check this [sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjaybpxe/)

I placed the `.close` button inside of `.modal-dialog` instead of the `.modal-header` and added some css. hope this helps.

```
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
}
.modal-dialog {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide example how you want it to look. HTML CSS code would be nice.
Assuming you are using this [w3School bootstrap modal](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

```
.modal-header .close {
    margin-top: -39px;
    margin-right: -12px;
}
```